# Как описать переменную, чтобы других модулях она была константа?

Tags: c, переменные, константа

Как описать на языке С переменную (поле) так, чтобы в одном модуле (в программе) она была константой, а в другом (в реализации) переменной? То есть определить свойство переменной как только для чтения для одного текста и как изменяемую переменную для другого?

Comment: Можно сделать константную ссылку: `int foo; const int& bar = foo;`

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian  Да, но это в С++. А в С?

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian: И каким образом предложенный вами С++ вариант скроет `foo` от тех модулей, которые должны иметь констаннтый доступ???

Comment: @AnT Нужно объявить foo как static a bar как public.

Comment: @Вячеслав в первой редакции тег C++ стоял, не заметил, что в тексте про C уже вопрос, сорри

Comment: @AnT скрыть вроде задачи не стояло

Comment: Эелемнтарно. Объявляете поле `const int *x;` и метод setter'а.